# Listando usuários de uma api em json em uma tabela html com javascript

Tags: javascript

Bem sou bem novo no javascript e gostaria de saber como faço pra fazer a chamada da API no JS e logo em seguida preciso de um loop pra listar chamados, eles estão em array no json. Alguém pode me ajudar nessa dúvida

código que estou usando para chamada da API

```
function listAtendimento() {
let body = '{"msg": "" }'

$.ajax({
    url: "link da api",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: body,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Olá Victor, poste o código que já desenvolveu para receber mais ajuda e se quiser de uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo primeiro você cria o html correspondente a uma lista:

```
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Após isso dentro do success do seu ajax faça o loop em seu array:

```
seuArray.map((el) => $('#lista').append("<li>"+ el.propriedadeQueSeraMostrada +"</li>"))
```

Assim você fará um loop no seu array e adicionará uma li para cada elemento do seu array na sua lista.

Espero ter ajudado.